# StackOverFlow Error When Using Type Converter with Room

Tags: java, android, android-room

I am interacting with TheMovieDatabase API, found [here](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies).

I am trying to pull the popularity field, which is of object type `Number`.

Room requires a Type Converter for this object, which I have integrated below:

```
public class NumberConverter {

@TypeConverter
public static Number toNumber(Integer integer){
    return integer == null ? null : toNumber(integer); }


@TypeConverter
public static Integer toInt(Number number){
    return number == null ? null : number.intValue();
  }


}
```

When I load my app, I immediately receive a StackOverFlow error referencing this line:

```
        return number == null ? null : number.intValue();
```

Note: I am also using `Executors` to handle the read and writes asynchronously:

```
public class AppExecutors{

//for Singleton Instantiation
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private static AppExecutors sInstance;
private final Executor diskIO;
private final Executor mainThread;
private final Executor networkIO;

public AppExecutors(Executor diskIO, Executor mainThread, Executor networkIO) {
    this.diskIO = diskIO;
    this.mainThread = mainThread;
    this.networkIO = networkIO;
}


public static AppExecutors getsInstance(){
    if (sInstance == null){
        synchronized (LOCK){
            sInstance = new AppExecutors(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(),
                    Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3),
                    new MainThreadExecutor());
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
};

public Executor diskIO(){return diskIO;};
public Executor mainThread(){return mainThread;}
public Executor netWorkIO(){return networkIO;}

private static class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor{

    private android.os.Handler mainThreadHandler = new android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void execute(@NonNull Runnable runnable) {
        mainThreadHandler.post(runnable);
    }
   }



}
```

EDIT: Referenced [TheMovieDatabase](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies) documentation

Comment: How are you calling `toInt()`?

Comment: "I am trying to pull the popularity field, which is of object type Number" -- that is a singularly awful choice for a data type for a field. "I immediately receive a StackOverFlow error" -- since `Integer` is a subclass of `Number`, I suspect that Room is getting confused with the `TypeConverter` code. Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Agreed, I was simply following the documentation: https://github.com/troy21688 for complete code. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check this function in your code:

`@TypeConverter
public static Number toNumber(Integer integer){
    return integer == null ? null : toNumber(integer); }`

You have an infinite `recursion` going on here and maybe that's why you are getting the `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: How would I remove the recursion?

Comment: try `return integer == null ? null : (Number)integer; }` or `return integer == null ? null : integer; }`.  "Integer is a subclass of Number, so you can use it like an instance of Number or cast it, as you choose". Check this post for more details: https://coderanch.com/t/367647/java/cast-int-Number